# Is there a way to streamline the creation of similar multi-component elements in HTML5?

Tags: html

I am new to HTML and I want to implement a rather large list of user options that use radio buttons. The various items all have a similar format and look like this:

```
<p>
  "Question 1 text"
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q1_id1">
  <label for="q1_id1">Yes</label>
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q1_id2">
  <label for="q1_id2">No</label>
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q1_id3">
  <label for="q1_id3">Maybe</label>
</p>
<p>
  "Question 2 text"
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q2_id1">
  <label for="q2_id1">Yes</label>
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q2_id2">
  <label for="q2_id2">No</label>
  <input style="radio" name="question1" id="q2_id3">
  <label for="q2_id3">Maybe</label>
</p>
```

etc.

Since so much of this code is repetitive, I was wondering if there was a way to declare an html object or something (I know html isn't an object oriented language), like you would do in other programming languages so you could have something like this:

1. Define html object that contains text and three radio buttons
2. Add a list of those objects to the document, changing only the question text and the button label text

in just a few lines of html.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to resort to copy-pasting?

Comment: Usually you’d use a template engine for this. JavaScript that creates the elements in the browser could also be an option. What’s most appropriate depends on what exactly you’re building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this in HTML. There are other ways:

1) You can use a template language to generate the appropriate HTML on the server before you send it to the user. Depending on your server, there are different options for this.

2) You can send the input's data to the user's browser as JSON and generate the HTML using Javascript. This can be more economical if the element repeats many times, like in a large data table.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that might be the case. Are either of the methods you described strongly preferred for any reason other than saving programmer time (for example improving readability of code or run time)? I just want to get in the habit of some best practices whenever possible.

Comment: If there are a few buttons, generating them on the server is generally faster. There are probably more programmers that understand server side code.  On the other hand, JavaScript can perform better if you have a lot of buttons, because the files you send to the client are smaller.